# Change content of GroupBox dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `GroupBox`. This box contains one `UserControl`

```
<GroupBox Header="NewsBox">

    <GroupBox.Content>
        <NewsDay:NewsDayControl DataContext="{Binding SelectedNews}"/>
    </GroupBox.Content>

</GroupBox>
```

Now, I want to change the Content of the `GroupBox` dynamically depending on a selected Tab of a `TabControl`.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  ElementName=TabControl, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
</DataTrigger>
```

This is the other `UserControl` which should appear, if the Tab with Index 1 is selected:

```
<Imprint:ImprintControl DataContext="{Binding SelectedImprint}"/>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Style` with triggers like this.

```
<GroupBox Header="NewsBox">
    <GroupBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="GroupBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  ElementName=TabControl, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <NewsDay:NewsDayControl DataContext="{Binding SelectedNews}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  ElementName=TabControl, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Imprint:ImprintControl DataContext="{Binding SelectedImprint}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </GroupBox.Style>
</GroupBox>
```